# integers array return type

Tags: c++, c, return-type

I want to know if I can make a function return an array of integers. I tried code that looks like this:

```
int function[](){
    code;
}
```

and I have tried code that looks like this:

```
int[] function(){
    code;
}
```

Neither work. Any suggestions?

Comment: it's not usually practical to return an array.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656532/returning-an-array-using-c, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264304/how-to-return-an-array-from-a-method, or others

Comment: The answers will be relateivly differnt

Comment: What none of the answers are telling you: arrays aren't copyable or assignable, so you cannot return one by value. You need to either return something else, or find another means to copy the interesting data into a pre-existing array. And any possible solutions will depend on the language. Unfortunately you have tagged two.

Comment: C and C++ might be a little different regarding this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try `std::array<int, N>` if the size of the array is already known. In other situations, use `std::vector<int>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void print_vec(int arr[])
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.insert(vec.begin(), arr, arr+3);
    for (auto x: vec) {
         std::cout << ' ' << x;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main ()
{
    int arr[] = { 501,502,503 };
    print_vec(arr);
}

Output:

501 502 503
```

Link to compiler -> [Compiler Link](http://ideone.com/fesogD)

Comment: Why the downvote? I did everything that the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
int* function ()
{}
```

But don't forget that calling function now owns the responsibility for that array i.e for deleting that array.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a pointer to an array if that array is created with the `new` operator on the heap. Like this:

```
int* get_an_array(int array_size)
{
   int arr = new int[array_size];

   return arr;
}
```

Remember that you will responsible for deleting that array later.

Note 1:
You cannot return a pointer to a locally created array (placed on the stack). For example:

```
int* get_an_array(int array_size)
{
   int arr[array_size];

   return arr;
}
```

that array is destroyed as soon as you exit the function.

Note 2:
Consider using STL vectors instead of arrays. With STL vectors: 1) You won't need to know the number of elements before you call the function. 2) You won't need to dynamically create the array. (Also returning a vector by value is usually fast as the compiler takes advantage of copy elision (RVO)).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *func1(int year){
    static int array[][13] = {
        {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31},
        {0, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31},
    };
    return array[year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0];
}
int (*func2(int year))[13]{
    static int array[][13] = {
        {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31},
        {0, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31},
    };
    return &array[year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0];
}

int main(void){
    int *p1 = func1(2000);
    int (*p2)[13] = func2(2000);

    printf("%d\n", p1[2]);
    printf("%d\n", (*p2)[2]);

    return 0;
}
```