# Return array from a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I try to return an array from function in C++.
I made a very easy function to demonstrate it.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int OneDimensional();

void main()
{
    int arr[3];
    arr = OneDimensional();

    cout<<"arr = " << arr[0] <<endl;

    cin.get(); cin.get();
}

int OneDimensional()
{
    int arr[3];
    cout << "Enter a number" <<endl;
    cin  >> arr[0];
    cout << "Enter a number" <<endl;
    cin  >> arr[1];
    cout << "Enter a number" <<endl;
    cin  >> arr[2]; 
    return arr;
}
```

But it fails with a lot of errors.

Comment: for further reading: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/3953764)

Comment: arr in OneDimensional allocates array on its stack and you are trying to return pointer to stack - very bad idea. Also a lot of bugs. Try read some book on C/C++ programming.

Comment: There are no bugs tho, other than the not working function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use a pointer.

```
int * OneDimensional()
{
    static int arr[3];
    cout << "Enter a number" <<endl;
    cin  >> arr[0];
    cout << "Enter a number" <<endl;
    cin  >> arr[1];
    cout << "Enter a number" <<endl;
    cin  >> arr[2]; 
    return arr;
}

void main()
{
    int *arr;
    arr = OneDimensional();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++ )// length is number of elements in array
   {
       cout<<"arr = "<< *(arr + i) << endl;
   }
}
```

Check the [example here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_return_arrays_from_function.htm)

Comment: Your function returns a pointer to a local temporary.

Comment: you're returning a dangling pointer

Comment: @randooom , i have used `static int arr[3];`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, program is working fine I have checked.

Comment: With this method you'll get the same array each time you call `OneDimensional`.

Comment: @Himanshu sure, once you have changed it to a static array, now the pointer to it won't get invalidated

Comment: And you should certainly not `delete[]` an array created without `new[]`.

Comment: @TartanLlama, yes you are  right. thanks.

Comment: `cin.get()` is missing and `length` is not declared, `static`is not necessary. But other than that, it works, thx!

Comment: @EdwardBlack, `length` you can pass according to number of array element you care using. in this program you can pass `3` in place of `length`.

Comment: @EdwardBlack if you don't use `static` then you'll return a dangling pointer.

Comment: @Himanshu one last question, does this also work with multi dimensional arrays?

Comment: @EdwardBlack Please have a look at the question which Piotr marked as a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264304/how-to-return-an-array-from-a-function), those answers are preferable to this.

Comment: @TartanLlama sorry if the question is dumb, but what is bad about "dangling pointers". Is it creating a memory leak?

Comment: @EdwardBlack dereferencing it leads to undefined behaviour. It might work today, but could crash your machine, order pizza or give you nasal demons tomorrow.

Answer (score -2):

- `int OneDimensional()` return only a `int` value, not an array.
- `main()` doesn't have a `return`

You need read more about C or C++.

Goold Luck!

Comment: *"main() doesn't have a return"*, `main` doesn't need an explicit return statement

Comment: Although it should be declared as returning an `int`.

Comment: @David Isla, maybe you are the one who should read a C++ book, lol

Comment: @EdwardBlack lol, yes sure! ^^