# Returning Arrays from C++ functions

Tags: c++, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, return

How do I return both multidimensional and unidimensional arrays, from C++ functions?
Please explain completely!

```
   return MArray[][];
   return Array[];
```

Comment: It depends on whether the function itself gets these arrays or it should create arrays itself.

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473438/return-array-in-a-function

And in more detail this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264304/how-to-return-an-array-from-a-function

Comment: The linked answers don’t make this clear so I’ll restate it here: **you cannot return arrays in C++**. It’s simply impossible. What you can do is *wrap* an array and return the wrapper, or to use a different, array-like structure instead. But you can’t return an array.