# Returning primitive type arrays in C++ (Java comparison)

Tags: c++, arrays

To clarify, my question is NOT the same as this one: [How to return an array from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264304/how-to-return-an-array-from-a-function)

The answers from that question basically say to return a pointer or use the array class.

In Java, you can return a primitive type array from a function (such as int[]). I want to know if you can return a primitive array WITHOUT using the array class.

EDIT:

I am expecting syntax like this:

```
int[] returnArrayFunc() { int a[2]; return a;}
```

EDIT #2:

I want to learn how to return arrays in C++, not Java.

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: Could you show some code of what sort of return type or syntax you're expecting?

Comment: You mean you want to return a copy of the array? Because returning pointer still 'returns the array'...

Comment: I added an example for the syntax i am looking for. Is returning the pointer the right way to do this?

Comment: No because returning a pointer to `a` would lead to a dangling pointer.  You would need to allocate `a` on the heap, then you should return a `std::unique_ptr` to show the transfer of ownership.

Comment: Richard Critten, can you please explain why that is? I tried it and my program crashed.

Comment: The short answer is you *cannot* in c++ return a raw c array by value. You need to come up with a workaround. `std::array` is a zero cost wrapper for c arrays and there is no real reason not to use them instead if they are available.

Comment: I don't see how this question is any different from the linked question you insist is not a duplicate.

Answer (score -4):

Your question is a bit ambiguous, because you are asking a C question about Java. Java doesn't provide access to pointers. "a primitive array WITHOUT using the array class" isn't meaningful in Java.

BTW, you should ask this question on the C++ forum.

Edit:

This is an answer: In short, No.