# Returning an array from a function to main in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, dynamic-memory-allocation, smart-pointers

How can I return this array to the main function for further use in my program?

```
int* enterMarks(int marks) {

int arr[marks];
cout << "Please enter " << marks << "marks (0<=Mark<=100):" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < marks; i++) {
    cout << i+1 << ">";
    cin >> arr[i];
}
cout << "Thank you..." << endl;

return *arr;
```

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead. You can return one as you would any other object.

Comment: Turn on your compiler's warnings.  It should have been able to warn you about this mistake.

Comment: You shouldn't be returning references or pointers to locally (stack) declared variables. Return either a pointer to a value stored on the heap or a copy.

Comment: It's impossible to return an array from a function in C++. In your code you've defined your function to return `int*` which is a pointer not an array. Use a `std::vector<int>` instead. It is possible to return a vector from a function.

Comment: Idiomatic C would be to have the caller allocate the array and pass it into the function that fills it `int enterMarks(int *arr, int marks) {...}`. In C++ you should  be using a `vector` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return an array from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264304/how-to-return-an-array-from-a-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters variable length arrays like this

```
int* enterMarks(int marks) {

int arr[marks];
//...
```

is not a standard C++ feature. In C++ the size of an array shall be a compile-time constant.

Secondly a pointer to a local array with automatic storage duration returned from the function will have invalid value because the local array will not be alive after exiting the function.

You need to have a dynamically allocated array.

Either you can use the smart pointer `std::unique_ptr`  that will point to a dynamically allocated array as shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<unsigned int[]> enterMarks( size_t marks ) 
{
    const unsigned HIGH_MARK = 100;

    auto arr = std::make_unique<unsigned int[]>( marks );

    std::cout << "Please enter " << marks 
              << " marks (0<=Mark<=" << HIGH_MARK << "):" << std::endl;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < marks; i++ ) 
    {
        std::cout << i+1 << "> ";
        std::cin >> arr[i];
    }

    std::cout << "Thank you..." << std::endl;

    return arr;
}

int main() 
{
    size_t n = 10;

    auto arr = enterMarks( n );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Please enter 10 marks (0<=Mark<=100):
1> 10
2> 20
3> 30
4> 40
5> 50
6> 60
7> 70
8> 80
9> 90
10> 100
Thank you...
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

Or you can use the standard class template std::vector as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<unsigned int> enterMarks( size_t marks ) 
{
    const unsigned HIGH_MARK = 100;

    std::vector<unsigned int> arr( marks );

    std::cout << "Please enter " << marks 
              << " marks (0<=Mark<=" << HIGH_MARK << "):" << std::endl;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < marks; i++ ) 
    {
        std::cout << i+1 << "> ";
        std::cin >> arr[i];
    }

    std::cout << "Thank you..." << std::endl;

    return arr;
}

int main() 
{
    size_t n = 10;

    auto arr = enterMarks( n );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look the same way as shown above.

Pay attention that there is no great sense to maje the array of the signed integer type `int`. It is better to use unsigned integer type `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 2):

```
int arr[marks];
```

This is a local variable and so you cannot return it, otherwise the behaviour is undefined, caused crashing etc.

You have two options

1) Allocate the array in the heap and return it

```
int *arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*marks);
...
return arr;
```

You must then `free` the arr in the calling function.

2) Better, use C++ vector and return it

```
std::vector<int> arr;
...
cin >> mark;
arr.push_back(mark);
...
return arr;
```

This way you don't have to remember to free the heap memory.

Comment: Could you please give me an example on how I could print this array out in the main function. I have not learned vectors yet.

Answer (score 2):

You should not return a pointer to a variable you define in the local scope of your function i.e. in your case `arr`.

Return a copy of `std::vector` instead.

```c
#include <vector>


vector<int> enterMarks(int marks) {
  vector<int> arr;
  cout << "Please enter " << marks << "marks (0<=Mark<=100):" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < marks; i++) {
    cout << i+1 << ">";
    int mark;
    cin >> mark;
    arr.push_back(mark);
  }
  cout << "Thank you..." << endl;

  return arr;
}
```

To print these value out in main, you can simply do the following.

```c
vector<int> arr = enterMarks(marks);
for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
  cout << "Mark " << i << " = " << arr[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example on how I could print this array out in the main function. I have not learned vectors yet.

Comment: Updated the answer with an example :)